# PHP: loop array output (increase variables)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I use the following code to output content of an array:

```
$txt = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $myarray[1], $myarray[2], $myarray[3], $myarray[4], $myarray[5], $myarray[6], $myarray[7]);
echo $txt; 

echo "<br />";

$txt = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $myarray[8], $myarray[9], $myarray[10], $myarray[11], $myarray[12], $myarray[13], $myarray[14]);
echo $txt; 

echo "<br />";

$txt = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $myarray[15], $myarray[16], $myarray[17], $myarray[18], $myarray[19], $myarray[20], $myarray[21]);
echo $txt; here
```

Now I want to loop it, I tried something like this:

```
for($a=1, $b=2, $c=3, $d=4, $e=5, $f=6, $g=7; $i<=count($myarray); $a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g +=7)
{

    $txt = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $myarray[$a], $myarray[$b], $myarray[$c], $myarray[$d], $myarray[$e], $myarray[$f], $myarray[$g]);
    echo $txt; 

}
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: What is your input and expected output. Please elaborate it more..unclear

Comment: Google: `PHP array_chunk()` + `PHP implode()`

Comment: Change the increment variables to $a+=7,$b+=7,$c+=7,$d+=7,$e+=7,$f+=7,$g +=7

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be:

- Increment `$i` by 7 on every iteration.
- Use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get 7 items with offset of `$i`.
- Use [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) what takes arguments as `array`.

Try this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($myArray); $i+=7) {
    echo vsprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", array_slice($myArray, $i, 7)).'<br />';
}
```

or use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), so code looks cleaner.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($myArray); $i+=7) {
    echo implode(" ", array_slice($myArray, $i, 7)).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$size = 6;

foreach(array_chunk($array, $size) as $values) {
    echo implode(' ', $values) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize and increment $i, i think that may cause the problem.

Please try this,

```
for($a=1, $b=2, $c=3, $d=4, $e=5, $f=6, $g=7,$i=1; $i<=3; $a+=7,$b+=7,$c+=7,$d+=7,$e+=7,$f+=7,$g+=7,$i++)
{
$txt = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $myarray[$a], $myarray[$b], $myarray[$c], $myarray[$d], $myarray[$e], $myarray[$f], $myarray[$g]);
echo $txt; 
}
```